# Taking over a WordPress site

Tags: wp-admin

So my company has a WordPress site but anyone who ever worked with it has left and all we have is the log-in information. We do not know if we had anyone design it or run it for us. But I do have admin log-in.

I am not a web designer or anyone that has done more than dabble but I know I'm missing something!

I have logged into the admin page and see the side task bar but nothing appears on the screen. I'm guessing I need to download something to my computer to get this to work but have no idea where to start.

Any help or ideas is much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: No additional software is needed to manage WordPress. What do you mean when you say that "_nothing appears on the screen_"? May you please [`edit`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/243132/edit) your question and provide a screenshot?

Comment: Screen shot has been added.

Comment: What happens when you click on another menu link? Are those pages blank as well? It's hard to narrow down what the exact issue may be. You could disable all of the plugins to see if that changes anything since it's possible that one of the plugins may be causing it. Also, the Dashboard just shows some summary boxes for site info.

Comment: Also possible that it's a theme or theme functions problem, not a plugin problem - and that's at least easier to check (go to Appearance/Manage Themes, and choose and activate a different Theme - preferably one of the WordPress "annuals" (2016, 2015, 2014, etc.)).

Comment: When I click the other menu items it's the same, nothing comes up.

Comment: Step 1: disable all plugins, and change to the default twentysixteen theme (download it from a fresh WP if it has been removed). Step 2: make sure that WP_DEBUG is set to true in wp-config.php. Step 3: Check for errors (make sure to check in the source code, they might be visually hidden behind the menu or something if the previous dev messed with the admin UI). Then let us know if there's errors.

Comment: I am not sure what any of that means Brian. I literally only have the login. I have never worked with this site and have no idea what wp-config.php is.

Comment: Do I need files set up? Is that the problem? When this was first set up did someone download wordpress and create a file folder that I'm not able to access so on my end it has nothing to pull from? I was just reading about WordPress and it mentions downloading and setting up a file folder...

Comment: In all honesty, you seem too unfamiliar with Wordpress, and possibly with site operation in general, to handle this problem by yourself. If no one in your company or a niece or nephew possesses the requisite skills, you may need to hire someone. Shouldn't be too expensive to get you up and running, though you'll likely need ongoing support/maintenance, too.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty unfamiliar. I'm hoping to find our FTP information and update the wordpress version to try that. If that does not work my recommendation to the company will be to hire someone. Thank you all for your help! Hopefully once I find the FTP information I will be able to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of Wordpress. Because you do not have proper access to the panel, you need to update as follows:

1. Access your FTP and copy the files that are there to your computer as a backup.
2. Download the latest version of Wordpress here: https://wordpress.org/
3. If they are zipped, extract the downloaded file.
4. Upload and replace

IMPORTANT:
Do not replace the following folder:
public_html / wp-content /

Do not replace the following file:
public_html / wp-config.php /

Ps: Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Thank you, we are currently trying to find our FTP information. That is one problem I've realized I have. After we get access I will try what you are saying. Thank you!